# Ext JS 4 -- tree panel and conditional card display

Tags: extjs

I am working on an application in Ext JS that uses a tree for navigation. In the center pane (using the border layout) I use a card view. Selecting a node on the tree changes the card that is displayed. Each card may contain quite different components.

So far, this hasn't been very difficult to do. But here is the issue. Some of the cards should only be displayed if certain conditions are met. For example, I have a card that allows the user to view an uploaded CSV file. This card is shown when the user clicks on the "View CSV file" node in the tree. However, if the user hasn't uploaded a CSV file yet, and he clicks on that node, I'd like to instead show a card with a file upload field so the user can upload the CSV file.

Right now, I have the following in my controller init:

```
this.control({
    'nav-tree': {
        select: {
           fn: function(model, record, index){
               record.handler();  
           },
           scope: this
        }
    }
})
```

`record.handler()` is a function defined in my model that reads a property, cardId, from the model and switches the layout to the card with that ID (it also does a few other things.)

I realize I could throw a bunch of if statements in my handler function to check if the CSV file is uploaded and load the appropriate card, but there are at least two drawbacks to that approach I can see:

(1) It's very inelegant, and
(2) The conditions I'm checking for are going to get more complex, making the if statements hard to read and difficult to manage.

I'm hoping there is a better Ext JS-friendly solution to this difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely code that should be in the controller, the model shouldn't be making decisions about what views to load. Certainly you can add helper functions on to your model to retrieve data/check data conditions, but any decision making should happen in the controller.

Comment: Good point. I should excise the handler() call and just read the property from the selected record right in the controller.

Comment: I'm wondering now if it wouldn't be better to add items _to the tree_ as different conditions in the application are satisfied.